# How to edit the generated table through tabulator Plugin

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I wanted to edit the table which was generated through json data.
However, I can achieve this by using below configuration

```js
//define the table columns
columns:[ 
    {title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"input"},
],
```

But in my case the columns are auto generated and i cannot mentioned as above snippet but i need those to be edited .

Answer (score 0):

As of Tabulator v4.8 you can now add definitions to columns generated through ***autoColumns***

The new ***autoColumnsDefinitions*** option lets you define definitions for column should they appear in the data. You can use it in one of three ways:

#### Callback function

If you pass a function to the ***autoColumnsDefinitions*** option, it will be called when the column definitions have been generated. It will be passed the column definition array for you to manipulate. The callback must return the array of definition objects.

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data:tabledata,
    autoColumns:true,
    autoColumnsDefinitions:function(definitions){
        //definitions - array of column definition objects

        definitions.forEach((column) => {
            column.headerFilter = true; // add header filter to every column
        });

        return definitions;
    },
});
```

#### Column Definition Array

If you pass an array of column definition objects to the ***autoColumnsDefinitions*** option, the properties for each object will be copied over to the generated column definitions.

Objects are matched by field, so you must set the ***field*** property for each object in the array.

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data:tabledata,
    autoColumns:true,
    autoColumnsDefinitions:[
        {field:"name", editor:"input"}, //add input editor to the name column
        {field:"age", headerFilter:true}, //add header filters to the age column
    ],
});
```

Definitions will only be applied to columns generated by autocolums, others will be ignored. So you can use this to define options for possible columns, that will only be included if they are needed.

#### Field Name Lookup Object

If you pass an object to the ***autoColumnsDefinitions*** option, it will lookup the definitions for each column, with the field name of the column used as the property name in the object

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data:tabledata,
    autoColumns:true,
    autoColumnsDefinitions:{
        name: {editor:"input"}, //add input editor to the name column
        age: {headerFilter:true}, //add header filters to the age column
    },
});
```

Definitions will only be applied to columns generated by autocolums, others will be ignored. So you can use this to define options for possible columns, that will only be included if they are needed.

Full details for all of these options can be found in the [AutoColumns Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/columns#autocolumns)

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to implement this.  

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at t.setColumns (tabulator.min.js:2)
    at t.generateColumnsFromRowData (tabulator.min.js:2)
    at tabulator.min.js:3
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at s.setData (tabulator.min.js:3)
    at tabulator.min.js:6

Comment: Without knowing how your table is setup it is hard to offer advice on this. Please create a JS fiddle to demonstrate your issue

Comment: Nevermind - not sure what I did wrong, but I have it working.